# Eigenvalues using eig

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue

I have a simple 2x2 matrix:

```
A = [-2.0883*10^7 , 1.3975*10^7 ; 1.3975*10^7 , -9.3514*10^6]
```

by using eig(A) I got the following eigenvalues:

```
(-3.0235*10^7, -9.3132*10^-10)
```

However, by using some other calculators on the web I obtain this answer:

```
(-3.0235*10^7 , 507.32)
```

What should I do in Matlab to obtain the eigenvalues like in the second result?

Example of result:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: could you do in your Matlab [V, L] = eig(A) and then give us the result of V, L and `V * L * inv(V)`

Comment: You should then check that what you get from V * L * inv(V) is A otherwise something is off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalues at least as mathematical constructs are completely well-defined and unambiguous (except for their order). If the eigenvalues are off this either means that one of the results is wrong, or the matrix is so ill-conditioned that eigenvalue solvers don't always give the correct (exact) result.

In your case you must have misread something:

```
>> A = [-2.0883*10^7 , 1.3975*10^7 ; 1.3975*10^7 , -9.3514*10^6];
>> eigvals = eig(A);
>> eigvals(1)

ans =

  -3.0235e+07

>> eigvals(2)

ans =

  507.3209
```

That is, the second set of eigenvalues is correct.

---

Regarding your update:

For 2x2 matrices the eigenvalues can easily be computed on paper. The two eigenvalues happen to be

```
e1 = trace(A)/2 + sqrt(trace(A)^2/4 - det(A))
e2 = trace(A)/2 - sqrt(trace(A)^2/4 - det(A))
```

if you solve the second-degree characteristic polynomial. For your exact numbers:

```
>> tr = A(1,1) + A(2,2); % computed by hand to avoid magic
>> d = A(1,1)*A(2,2) - A(1,2)*A(2,1); % same
>> tr/2 + sqrt(tr^2/4 - d)

ans =

  507.3209

>> tr/2 - sqrt(tr^2/4 - d)

ans =

  -3.0235e+07
```

However, your updated code shows that your input isn't exactly what your example is; your true input comes from an earlier calculation and `A` above is only a truncated version of the floats in the matrix. Now, look at the two terms appearing in the eigenvalues:

```
>> format long
>> tr/2            

ans =

   -15117200

>> sqrt(tr^2/4 - d)

ans =

     1.511770732088699e+07
```

As you can see, one term is -15117200 (exact), the other is 15117707.32088699 (approximate; coming from a square root). Now, these numbers are huge in magnitude and *almost* the same (except a sign). This means their sum will experience cancellation, and this cancellation will be very sensitive to the specific values of the variables.

In other words, your specific `G2{1}` contains values such that the above two terms cancel *almost exactly*, due to some underlying symmetry. Believe what MATLAB is telling you, your eigenvalues are fine. But when you copied a truncated version of the matrix into a separate eigenvalue computation (just like I did above), you got the wrong result due to the cancellation being only partial.

---

You gave more specific values of your matrix in a comment:

```
>> B = [-2.088317534729117e+07, 1.397451196178947e+07 ; 1.397451196178947e+07 , -9.351402807405353e+06];
>> tr = trace(B);         
>> d = det(B);
>> tr/2

ans =

    -1.511728907734826e+07

>> sqrt(tr^2/4 - d)

ans =

     1.511728907734826e+07
```

Mystery solved.

Comment: Using exactly same code as you did and getting different answer, any chance it something connected to properties in solvers?

Comment: @benb what is your matlab version? I wouldn't expect this to happen unless there's a huge version difference, but I don't know what MATLAB uses under the hood. I updated my answer with an exact computation of eigenvalues; as you can see it's simple and shouldn't break easily.

Comment: Also, regarding your update: is `G2{1}` exact? I mean, do you get the same (different from mine) result if you copy-paste _your_ exact example code? If `G2{1}` is numerically different from what your example is (due to truncated floats), it could explain a difference in the result.

Comment: The exact values of G2{1} are: [-2.088317534729117e+07, 1.397451196178947e+07 ; 1.397451196178947e+07 , -9.351402807405353e+06]. what is weird is when I wrote the example you gave on workspace it gave me also 507. When did in code it didnt.

Comment: @benb I think I solved your problem, please see my update.

Comment: Thing is that im trying to compare some result to a paper from like 30 years ago and I suspect that they didnt use that precision like Matlab does and thats why I get different results. Is there a way to make the values be less precise in this calculation?

Comment: @benb I don't think so. The main problem is that your matrix has `cond(G2{1}) = 9.8e15`. That's a huge condition number, making your matrix highly ill-conditioned. That's why subtle changes to the matrix elements change the result this much. For what it's worth, I'd expect a _numerically exact_ zero eigenvalue to be correct with much higher probability. I'd wager your results are correct (and correctly more precise than the original work). You could try working with `single` precision, but then the other eigenvalue becomes exactly `-0.5` (from `eig`; and exact `0` from the analytical form)...

Comment: @benb perhaps if you start with single-precision from the very start of your calculation you could end up with similar results. But for that you'd have to follow the exact same algorithm, otherwise I'd expect the ill-conditioned nature of the problem to lead to numerically different results anyway.

Comment: If the determinant is very small use the alternative form of the root of `x²+px+q=0` in `x = (-p+sqrt(p²-4q))/2=-2q/(p+sqrt(p²-4q))` for `p>0` or with the other root sign for `p<0` to avoid cancellation in the difference.